# Is there a way to loop/iterate a series of str_extract calls in R?

Tags: r, string, iteration, text-extraction

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this but I've hit a dead end.

I have a large text dataset, and I want to know which countries are mentioned in each document. Sometimes it will say "afghanistan", sometimes "afghan", but since those are referring to the same country I want to only str_extract the first mention of either of those words. I have a pattern vector that therefore looks like this:

```
pattern <- c("afghanistan|afghan", "algeria|algerian", "albania|albanian", "angola|angolan", "argentina|argentine")
```

```
text <- c("the first stop on the trip is afghanistan, where he will meet the afghan president", "then he will leave afghanistan and head to argentina", "meetings with the afghan president in afghanistan should last 1 hour, and meetings with the argentine president in argentina should last 2 hours")
```

The goal is a series of vectors/df column that looks like the following:

```
c("afghanistan")
c("afghanistan", "argentina")
c("afghan", "argentine")
```

I originally made a long match pattern for all of the countries and nationalities all together and used str_extract_all() + unique() - this worked perfectly except when a text used both "afghanistan" and "afghan", in which case that country would be double counted.

I've tried various versions of map(), mapply(), etc and it usually results a list filled with character(0).

The closest I've gotten is a for loop:

```
country <- as.character(1:length(pattern)) #placeholder vector

for(i in 1:length(pattern)){
    country[i] = str_extract(text, pattern[i])
}
```

This gives a vector of the correct length, but filled with NAs.

Any ideas on how to iterate a str_extract() call like this would be appreciated!

Comment: What did your long pattern look like exactly and what function did you use it with?

Comment: The original pattern was: c("afghanistan|afghan|algeria|algerian|albania|albanian|angola|angolan|argentina|argentine")
So I used str_extract_all(text, pattern)  and then map(country, unique).
This definitely worked but like I said it double counted some of the countries when they appeared in two different forms (ie argentina and argentine would be 2 different observations when I'd like it to be just 1).

Comment: What is the _exact_ output you want from this text?  This is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the NA values. FOr example using `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
text |> 
  map(function(t) map_chr(pattern, ~str_extract(t, .))) |>
  map(~.x[!is.na(.x)])
# [[1]]
# [1] "afghanistan"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "afghanistan" "argentina"  
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "afghan"    "argentine"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to just form a single regex alternation and use `str_extract_all()`:

```r
pattern <- c("afghanistan|afghan", "algeria|algerian", "albania|albanian", "angola|angolan", "argentina|argentine")
regex <- paste(pattern, collapse="|")
text <- c("the first stop on the trip is afghanistan, where he will meet the afghan president", "then he will leave afghanistan and head to argentina", "meetings with the afghan president in afghanistan should last 1 hour, and meetings with the argentine president in argentina should last 2 hours")
countries <- str_extract_all(text, regex)
countries

[[1]]
[1] "afghanistan" "afghan"     

[[2]]
[1] "afghanistan" "argentina"  

[[3]]
[1] "afghan"      "afghanistan" "argentine"   "argentina"
```

Note that you are correct to place more specific matches ahead of less specific ones.  For example, `afghanistan` appears before `afghan` in the alternation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is what I did originally, but then it extracts both "afghanistan" and "afghan", which are both referring to the same country. That's why I'm hoping to make it essentially a series of OR calls...give me either "afghanistan" or "afghan" but not both. Also give me either "argentina" or "argentine" but not both. Hopefully that makes sense!